# In vim, how can I add a carriage return to a register using setreg?

Tags: vim, carriage-return, vim-registers

I have this command in my .vimrc:

```
vip:normal @g<CR>
```

When I set the register 'g' by typing in the buffer, like this, it works:

```
qg<CR>jq
```

If I type :registers, it shows:

```
--- Registers ---

"g   ^Mj
```

After that, typing @g results in a carriage return and then the cursor moves to the next line. The ^M appears in a special color.

However, when I use the setreg command in my vimrc, if I type @g, nothing happens.

```
call setreg('g','^Mj')
```

If I type :registers, it shows:

```
--- Registers ---

"g   ^Mj
```

The ^M is not in a special color.

I have the following in my .vimrc:

```
map <CR> :call MyFunction<CR>
```

The carriage return I want to store in the register is to run MyFunction. MyFunction is called perfectly as long as I fill the buffer manually rather than using setreg.

Where have I gone wrong? My platform is Linux.

Comment: How did you input ^M in `call setreg('g','^Mj')`? Did you use ctrl-v ctrl-m? Or just typed a caret and a M?

Comment: caret M... ah... i had tried typing caret v caret m and that failed. I didn't realize you actually have to type ctrl-v ctrl-m in insert mode, not write the string "^V^M". Thanks for that! Actually hitting those keys worked. The register is set properly. I appreciate your help.

Comment: ctrl-v <enter> is what I normally use to get `^M`.

Answer (score 12):

You are looking for `"\<cr>"` or `"\r"`

```
call setreg('g',"\<cr>j")
call setreg('g',"\rj")
```

or more simply

```
let @g = "\<cr>j"
let @g = "\rj"
```

For more help

```
:h expr-quote
:h let-@
```

Answer (score 5):

In a general rule avoid ascii control characters (below 0x20) inside the lines of your vim scripts. When you read your `vimrc` again if it has not enough lines, vim could detect a bad line termination pattern (mac?)

Use `nr2char(13)` to include a `^M` in a string literal.

```
call setreg('g', nr2char(13).'j')
```

Otherwise as sidyll told you in his comment, control characters can be entered using CTRL-V in insert mode.

Answer (score 1):

The top answer doesn't always work.
Providing `\n` did the trick in my case.

```
:let @a="foo"
:let @a="\nbar"
```

Make sure to use double quotes.

Comment: \n actually saved me when I needed an enter hit at the end of my macro. \n at the end of macro gives you ^J . while \<cr> and \<c-m> and \r all result in ^M^J